# How to group form's parameters for $_POST?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, grouping

Ex. (HTML file)

```
<form name='test' method='POST'>

<input type='text' name='name'>
<input type='text' name='surname'>
<input type='submit' name='sub'>

</form>
```

Now in the PHP file I'll get the `$_POST` like:

```
$_POST['name']= something
$_POST['surname']= something
etc...
```

What about if I want to "group" that to made a `$_POST` like this:

```
$_POST[name-of-the-form]['name']= something
$_POST[name-of-the-form]['surname']= something
etc...
```

How could I do it?

Comment: `<input type='text' name='name-of-the-form[name]'>`

Comment: /\ that's pretty much that.

Comment: so easy? thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AbraCadaver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222347/how-to-group-forms-parameters-for-post#comment54249378_33222347) is spot on here, all you do is name your form element accordingly. 
e.g.

```
<input type='text' name='name-of-the-form[name]'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this from a PHP file, you should use square braces andn the same name of in all element names:

```
<?php 
$formName = 'test';
?>
<form name='<?=$formName?>' method='POST'>

<input type='text' name='<?=$formName?>[name]'>
<input type='text' name='<?=$formName?>[surname]'>
<input type='submit' name='sub'>

</form>
```